# Not able to generate pdf using Jasper report

Tags: java, servlets, jasper-reports

I'm able to generate byte[] object, but while flushing the byte, then im getting the exception of

```
org.apache.catalina.connector.ClientAbortException: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe
```

I'm calling the servlet using Ajax

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'CertServlet',
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'post',

        data: data,
        success: function( data, textStatus, jQxhr ){

        error: function( jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown ){
            console.log( errorThrown );
        }
    });
```

My servlet code

```
byte[] output = null;
    try {
        output = JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdf(jasperPrint);
    } catch (JRException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    System.out.println(output); --> This has value
    response.reset();
    response.resetBuffer();
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline;filename=Sample.pdf");
    response.setContentType("application/pdf");
    response.setContentLength(output.length); 
    ServletOutputStream out = null;
    try {
        out = response.getOutputStream();       
        out.write(output,0,output.length);
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The total exception is

```
rg.apache.catalina.connector.ClientAbortException: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe
at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(OutputBuffer.java:410)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.append(ByteChunk.java:378)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.writeBytes(OutputBuffer.java:435)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1115)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:318)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:109)
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:153)
at
```

Any ideas whats going wrong?

Appreciate for the information.

Regards

Comment: what is the size of report? did you try increasing memory?